# Selenium IDE - "[error] Element css=#id56ed > span not found" this error is given by selenium

Tags: html, css, selenium

I am testing a website. On that website each element(buttons, links, check-boxes, etc.) has a Id, but each time any element is clicked, the id of that clicked element gets changed.

Now, when a particular suit is recorded like clicking on multiple links, buttons the id is matched and that task is recorded with that id of the element at that particular time. 
but when the test suit is played, error appears as "**[error] Element css=#id56ed > span not found**" in the **Log**

There is nothing else that could be compared while recording for the element like name or something else, only id is given for each element.

As css=#id56ed has changed now when playing this error appears. What script should be written so that changed id of that element should not break the flow of test suit and perform the same task and that error of css=#id**** > span not found get removed.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul> 
 <li class="tab0 selected">
  <a href="#" id="idb30">
   <span>Holiday homes</span>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="tab1">
  <a href="#" id="idb31">
   <span>Camping sites</span>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="tab2 last">
  <a href="#" id="idb32">
   <span>Hotel rooms</span>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>`
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: And the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because of dynamic IDs.  The ID of an element is different every time you open the page.  I really need to see the HTML of the page you are trying to interact with...but I'll try to write you a selector anyways.

On the line that fails, you have to rewrite your selector to: `css = "*[id^="id"] > span"`

I don't think that the above will work, because it will select more than the element you want...and if it doesn't, please post the HTML of the element you want to select (plus surrounding HTML), or read up on CSS yourself.

EDIT:

If you wanted to select the "Camping Sites" link, you could either do it by link text, or with the following selector:  `css = .tab1 span`

Comment: <ul>
<li class="tab0 selected"><a href="#" id="idb30"><span>Holiday homes</span></a></li>
<li class="tab1"><a href="#" id="idb31"><span>Camping sites</span></a></li>
<li class="tab2 last"><a href="#" id="idb32"><span>Hotel rooms</span></a></li>
</ul>

id="idb30", id="idb31", id="idb32" these ids get changed each time on reload or click on the link.

Comment: Well problem is solved by but to take that element of page, I used xpath of that element while recording wherever it takes id.